# Which set does this bag belong to? Blue and clear orange pieces

Tags: set-identification

Hi can you please help identify which product this belongs to? Bought this from second hand shop.

The spiked flail is part of a smaller bag - no number however it was in a larger bag with a large number 2 on it, below which are the numbers 304R7:

[image: bricks label 304r7]

Hope this helps in identifying it.

Comment: You mean this: https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4613938 ?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the bag?

Comment: Updated my answer with set identification based on the picture.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the title of the post and Larme’s clarifying comment, you are looking at [59232 Minifig, Weapon Spiked Flail/Mace](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=59232) in a bag with date code 304R7 (which indicates this bag was produced in 2017).

[image]

Looking at BrickLink, [there are several sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?itemType=P&itemNo=59232&in=S&v=1&oV=Y&srt=2&srtAsc=D) made in 2017 that have this element in Flat Silver (no other color was produced recently). There is one set from 2016 but that set did not come with bags AFAIK. Most are from the Nexo Knights range, but one is from the Super Hero Girls line. If the bag has no large number on it, it must have come from a small set, for example [70361 Macy’s Dropbot Dragon](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70361-1). If the bag does have a large number on it (1, 2, 3 etc) it will be from a larger set. Without more information on what is in the bag besides the Flail, it is impossible to narrow the set down further.

UPDATE: Now that a bag picture has been provided, it is clear this bag belongs to set [70351 Clay’s Falcon Fighter Blaster](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70351-1) from the Nexo Knights theme. The [Technic connector with hole in the middle in Orange](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32034) is only in this set (out of all the sets on the list containing the Flail).

[image]

Comment: Bags without large numbers on them are also found inside of bags with large numbers on them in some larger sets, when the only knowledge of where it comes from is "second hand shop", we can't really rule out that it's a larger set where a numbered bag was opened, but the smaller unnumbered bags inside weren't.

Comment: Now that a picture of the bag has been supplied it should hopefully be possible to narrow the set down by inspecting the other parts in the bag.

Comment: Yes, posted the other answer on an account that asked me to register. Thank you for pointing me to the merge account. Thank you all for your help. I found the instructions online and successfully assembled clay's falcon fighter blaster. However, I am missing bag #1 and had a few extra pieces left.